# Python says: AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute '

Tags: python, count, attributeerror

I am writing a program with Python that will count the frequent characters in a file. The character it counts is determined by the user. I keep getting this message and I have been trying for the longest to figure it out with no avail:

```
filename = open('all-Names.txt', 'r')
character = input("Enter character: ")
x = filename.count(character) 
print(x)
filename.close()
```

Comment: I think my friend that is pretty obvious that there's not exist a count method in TextIOWrapper or at least it's not configured correctly. Actually i think you shouldn't pass the character variable at all to the count method

Comment: As Confucius said, "If names be not correct, language is not in accordance with the truth of things. If language be not in accordance with the truth of things, affairs cannot be carried on to success."  In other words: don't call something `filename` if it's not a file name.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `count()` method on a file object. You should iterate over file lines and sum up counts for every line:

```
character = input("Enter character: ")

with open('all-Names.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(sum(line.count(character) for line in f))
```

Demo:

```
$ cat all-Names.txt 
test
test2
test3
test4
test5
$ python
...
>>> character = input("Enter character: ")
Enter character: t
>>> with open('all-Names.txt', 'r') as f:
...    print(sum(line.count(character) for line in f))
... 
10
```